# htaccess Rewrite Rule Format

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F,L]


# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules

RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]

RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]


# For Friendly URLs

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/keyword1/(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)test-keyword(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/keyword2/(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/keyword3/(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/keyword4/(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/test-keyword/(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
```

All rules are working except this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)test-keyword(.*)$ /page-handler.html [L]
```

What I need to achieve with this rule is to rewrite the URL when a user enters a link as follows: domain.com/link-name/test-keyword, where test-keyword will always be the last node (without trailing slash).

Could someone give suggestions as to why it is not working please?

Comment: Is `domain.com/link-name/test-keyword` causing 404?

Comment: Yes it is - it's returning a 404 error.

Comment: As per your rule it should be going to `/index.php?q=link-name/test-keyword`

Comment: I would like to change it to go to index.php/link-name/test-keyword. How can I modify that rule to make it so?

Comment: That is not what you asked in question. You first asked to use `/page-handler.html` for this pattern.